# How to remap Autocomplete on Control+N, to Control+Space?

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion, insert-mode

I am trying to remap this functionality:
[image]
to Ctrl+Space, by using this line in `.vimrc`

```
inoremap <C-Space> <C-n>
```

However, I can not seem to get it to work.
If I press Ctrl+Space after starting up, I get this error:

```
E29: No inserted text yet
```

Which I suppose is already mapped to a clipboard which tracks your last input.
I would rather swap the functionality as auto-complete is more important to me.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "Autocomplete".

Comment: If it's native `:h ins-completion` you're talking about, then you should be good to go with `inoremap <C-space> <C-n>`

Comment: @klaus For what its worth, I was going to send a screenshot, but it stopped working so... Basically its when it gives you a box of options and keywords you can cycle through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your terminal send `^@` as `<c-space>` to vim, `^@` is `ctrl-@`, it's equivalent
to `<Nul>` in vim, check [:h keycodes](https://vimhelp.org/intro.txt.html#keycodes) if you have doubts.

You get `E29: No inserted text yet` error message because [:h i_CTRL-@](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-%40) is trying to insert previously inserted text (it doesn't exist).

To fix it, use:

```
inoremap <Nul> <c-n>
```

or

```
inoremap <c-@> <c-n>
```

or

```
map <Nul> <c-space>
map! <Nul> <c-space>
inoremap <c-space> <c-n>
```

Personally i think you should get used to `<c-n>`, it's one of the most useful shortcut key in vim.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you’ve got the map syntax backwards (see `:help :map`): try

```
inoremap <C-Space> <C-n>
```

Also see `:help ins-completion`

Comment: You were right, I had it backwards, however the remap still has not worked. I updated the question; thanks for fixing that.